# Как лучше сравнить изменения на web-страничке?

Tags: javascript

Пришла идея написать расширение для браузера. Суть: в настраиваемый промежуток времени запускается функция, которая сканирует(парсит) веб-страницу и сравнивает эту страницу с предыдущей версией этой же страницы за настраиваемый промежуток времени, т.е. ищет изменения. Вопрос: каждый раз парсить страницу и сравнивать или же есть другой вариант сравнения версий? Предположу, что частый парсинг будет забирать ресурсы... Подкиньте идею, кому это интересно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если достаточно получить `html` код, то можно взять, например, `innerHTML` нужного элемента, сохранить и сравнивать через интервал. В результате выводить отличия. Так как `innerHTML` или `outreHTML` представляют собой строку, то все будет быстро и четко. А искать отличия в строках это ну совсем просто.

Comment: спасибо, профессор, за идею